# build cpp program run on different version linux

Tags: c++, linux, build

Some linux program for example mongodb binary file can run on different version linux whatever the host machine gcc version and glibc version.

How to do that? static link all libs? But I heard of glibc is not supposed to be static linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an executable that is independent of the installed libraries, you must statically link it.

However, if the application isn't very large/complex to build, it's often better to either distribute the source and build on/for the target system, or pre-build for the most popular variants.

The reason that you don't want to statically link glibc (and all other libs that the application may use) is that even the most simple application becomes about 700K-1MB. Given that my distribution has 1900 entries in /usr/bin, that would make it around 2GB minimum, where now it is 400MB (and that includes beasts like clang, emacs and skype, all weighing in at over 7MB in non-statically linked form - they probably have more than a dozen library dependencies each - clang, for example, grows from under 10MB to around 100-120MB if you compile it with static linking).

And of course, with static linkage, all the code for each application needs to be loaded into memory as a separate copy. So the overall memory usage goes up quite dramatically.